# Perl dancer error execute method undefined

Tags: sqlite, perl, dancer

I was trying to make a website using perl dancer, below is my code. It seems to be correct but the page keeps loading and never enters the values in the database. When I cancel the page I get an error stating "`request to POST /appform crashed: Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value`". I can't figured out whats wrong in the code. If you have any other code please mention. 
I am using SQLite for database.
There is a database `campus.db`and I am inserting the value in `student` table.

```
post '/appform' => sub {

        my $q = CGI ->new;
        my $name = $q->param ("firstname");
        my $password = $q->param("password");
        my $mobile_no = $q->param("mobile");
        my $gender = $q->param("gender");
        my $email = $q->param("email");
        my $address = $q->param("address");
        my $sslc = $q->param("SSLC");
        my $hsc = $q->param("HSC");
        my $cgpa = $q->param("cgpa");
        my $languages = $q->param("lang");
        my $internships = $q->param("intern");
        my $preferred_loc = $q->param("country");
        my $sql = "insert into student(name,mobile_no,gender,email,address,sslc,hsc,cgpa,languages,internships,preferred_loc,password,applied_job,company_applied) values ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?');";
        my $sth = database->prepare($sql); 
        $sth->execute($name,$mobile_no,$gender,$email,$address,$sslc,$hsc,$cgpa,$languages,$internships,$preferred_loc,$password) or die $sth->errstr;
        #$sth->execute();   
        $sth-> finish;
        set_flash('New entry posted!');
            redirect '/';
    };
```

Comment: Double check the content of `$sth` (from the error message, it is `undef`) before using it in `$sth->execute()`

Comment: You should check whether your database connection is still open. There are hooks to use with the Database plugin, apparently. `https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer-Plugin-Database/lib/Dancer/Plugin/Database.pm#HOOKS`

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `database` keyword to get a database handle. I'm guessing that's coming from [Dancer2::Plugin::Database](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Database) (it would be useful if you could include information like this in your question).

The error says that you're calling `execute()` on an undefined value. You're calling `execute()` on the variable `$sth`. So `$sth` is undefined. You get `$sth` by calling `prepare()` on the database  handle returned from `database()`. So it looks like the `prepare()` call is failing. You should check the return value from that call and throw an error if it fails.

The most common reason for `prepare()` to fail is that you're trying to compile an SQL statement that contains an error. I can't see any obvious error in your SQL, but it's worth checking it by running it manually against your database.

I see you're using bind params in your SQL statement. That's a great idea, but please note that you don't need to quote the question marks in your SQL - the database driver will handle that for you. I don't think that's what is causing your problem though.

I also see that you're using CGI.pm inside your Dancer app to get the request parameters. To be honest, I'm slightly surprised that it works - but it's a terrible idea. Dancer has its own keywords that will give you this information. Look at `query_parameters()`, `body_parameters()` and `route_parameters()` in the [Dancer documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual.pod).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points made already, that your DBI prepare() call is probably failing (add error-checking to see why, e.g. `my $sth = database->prepare('...') or die "DB error: " . database->errstr`) and that you're using CGI.pm within a Dancer app (... don't do that, I'm surprised it would work *at all* - look at the Dancer documentation for how to access the params your app was sent), look also at the `quick_insert` convenience method provided by Dancer::Plugin::Database / Dancer2::Plugin::Database so that you don't have to write that SQL INSERT statement at all.